# How to merge github repositories?

Tags: git, github

There is this jQuery plugin [jQuery plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).. some guys made some modifications which one in their own github fork of this plugin..

i would like to have a version which is a merge of those 2 codes:

- https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar
- https://github.com/AbleTech/fullcalendar

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

As the original repository is also on github, the procedure would be somewhat like this. In a directory preferable for you, do:

```
git clone https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar.git fullcalendar
```

Then you add the two other repositories as remotes:

```
git remote add elhigu https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar.git
git remote add AlbeTech https://github.com/AbleTech/fullcalendar
```

And afterwards pull their changes to your local copy:

```
git pull elhigu master
git pull AlbeTech master
```

That should give you what you need, but be aware that you might get conflicts.

Comment: when i try to pull them i got this error: Vitor-MacBook:fullcalendar vitorbari$ git pull elhigu/master
fatal: 'elhigu/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: @VitorBari Sorry, I made a typo I always do when using the CLI. Please see my edit.